# How to display a textarea after selecting a certain option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `textarea` element that is not displayed. If the user selects "Other" option in the `select` element, the textarea should show, but it is not showing with the below code.

The following is my `select` element :

```
<select class="form-control" name="feed" id="feed" value="" style="width:540px">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="true">Please select</option>
    <!-- <option></option> -->
    <option value="Excellent" id="Excellent"> All text is excellent</option>

    <option value="Other" id="Other" onclick="showHide(this)"
        >Other feedback (free text)</option
    >
</select>
```

The following is my `textarea` element :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fb_text"></label>
    <textarea
        class="form-control"
        name="fb_text"
        id="fb_text"
        rows="5"
        placeholder="Describe yourself here..."
        value=""
        style="width:540px;display:none"
    ></textarea>
</div>
```

The following is my JS :

```
function showHide(elm) {
    var Fbtext = document.getElementById("fb_text");

    if (document.getElementById("feed").value == "Other") {
        Fbtext.classList.remove("hide");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call your showHide() function? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: I added onclick="showHide(this)" for the needed option above. Still not working. No errors show in the console.

Comment: What you need to do is use something similar to jQuery's `.on("change")` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass value from select using `onchange`event to your function and check if that value is equals to `Others` if yes `display textarea` else `hide it`. Working example :

```js
function showHide(elm) {


  if (elm == "Other") {
  //display textbox
    document.getElementById('fb_text').style.display = "block";
  } else {
  //hide textbox
    document.getElementById('fb_text').style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="feed" id="feed" value="" onchange="showHide(this.value)" style="width:540px">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="true">Please select</option>
  <!-- <option></option> -->
  <option value="Excellent" id="Excellent"> All text is excellent</option>

  <option value="Other" id="Other">Other feedback (free text)</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fb_text"></label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="fb_text" id="fb_text" rows="5" placeholder="Describe yourself here..." value="" style="width:540px;display:none"></textarea>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `change` event to the `select` element, see if the selected option is 'Other', hide the text area else show.

```js
const textareaEle = document.querySelector('textarea');

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  textareaEle.style.display = (this.value == 'Other') ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="form-control" name="feed" id="feed" value="" style="width:540px">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="true">Please select</option>
  <!-- <option></option> -->
  <option value="Excellent" id="Excellent"> All text is excellent</option>

  <option value="Other" id="Other">Other feedback (free text)</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fb_text"></label>
  <textarea class="form-control hide" name="fb_text" id="fb_text" rows="5" placeholder="Describe yourself here..." value="" style="width:540px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked but I understand in your code you try to remove a class (hide) that you have not assigned, because you hide the textarea with the attribute style

Please try this example, I understand in your example you use bootstrap, for demonstration I have added hide

```js
const feed = document.querySelector('#feed');
const fbtext = document.querySelector('#fb_text');

feed.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;

    if (value === 'Other') {
        fbtext.classList.remove('hide');

        return false;
    }

    fbtext.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select
    class="form-control"
    name="feed"
    id="feed"
    value=""
    style="width:540px"
>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="true">Please select</option>
    <option value="Excellent" id="Excellent"> Excellent</option>
    <option value="Other" id="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fb_text"></label>
    <textarea
        class="form-control hide"
        name="fb_text"
        id="fb_text"
        rows="5"
        placeholder="Describe yourself here..."
    ></textarea>
</div>
```